# Missing Exception in Boost Process

Tags: c++, exception, boost-filesystem, process-control

I want to use Boost Process eventhough it has not been release yet. I did

```
svn co svn://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/process/ boost-process
```

added `boost-process` to include path (`-I`) and `#included` `<boost/process.hpp>` but compilation complains about `filesystem_error` not being defined:

```
boost-process/boost/process/operations.hpp: In function ‘std::string boost::process::find_executable_in_path(const string&, std::string)’:
boost-process/boost/process/operations.hpp:85:36: error: ‘filesystem_error’ is not a member of ‘boost::filesystem3’
In file included from boost-process/boost/process.hpp:42:0,
                 from tests/../fio.hpp:22,
                 from tests/t_histogram.cpp:18:
boost-process/boost/process/operations.hpp:130:32: error: ‘filesystem_error’ is not a member of ‘boost::filesystem3’
```

I tried changing namespace to `boost::filesystem3` but with same results.

The defintion of `filesystem_error` is

```
  class BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE filesystem_error : public system::system_error
```

Is `BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE` hiding it?

Comment: In my experience it is better to use a newer version of boost.process, like soc2010: http://www.highscore.de/boost/gsoc2010/process.zip http://www.highscore.de/boost/gsoc2010/

Answer (score 13):

You need to edit the process/operations.hpp to remove this:

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
```

And instead say this:

```
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
```

I think this will make it compatible with Boost Filesystem v3 (which will soon be the only version, scheduled for Boost 1.48).

Comment: This helps indeed if using Boost.Process with Boost 1.52.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by passing -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 on my g++ command line.

Comment: Boost Filesystem v2 is deprecated and scheduled to disappear in the upcoming release of Boost.